# Consuming Web Service with JavaScript (returning dataSet)

Tags: javascript, web-services, ado.net, dataset

I consume a WebService .NET using Javascript with this code:

```
// This is where you can place your Javascript code
// var xmlHTTP;

function MButton1Click(event) {
testarTexto();
}


function WebSvc()   // Class Signature
   {
       WebSvc.prototype.CallWebService = function(url, soapXml, callback)
       {

           var xmlDoc = null;

           if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
           {
               xmlDoc = new XMLHttpRequest(); //Newer browsers
           }
           else if (window.ActiveXObject) //IE 5, 6
           {
               xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
           }

           if (xmlDoc)
           {
               var self = this;
               xmlDoc.onreadystatechange = function() { self.StateChange(xmlDoc, callback); };

               xmlDoc.open("POST", url, true);
               xmlDoc.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
               xmlDoc.setRequestHeader("Content-Length", soapXml.length);
               xmlDoc.send(soapXml);
           }
    else
           {
               if (callback)
               {
                   callback(false, "unable to create XMLHttpRequest object");
               }
           }
       };

       WebSvc.prototype.StateChange = function(xmlDoc, callback)
       {
 if (xmlDoc.readyState === 4)
           {
               var text = "";

               if (xmlDoc.status === 200)
               {
                   text = xmlDoc.responseText;
               }

               // Perform callback with data if callback function signature was provided,
               if (callback !== null)
               {
                   callback(xmlDoc.status === 200, text);
               }
           }
       };
   }


   function createSoapHeader(message)
   {
        var soap = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
   soap = soap + "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
   soap = soap + "  <soap:Body>";
   soap = soap + "    <TesteDeTexto xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">";
   soap = soap + "      <pTexto>" + message + "</pTexto>";
   soap = soap + "    </TesteDeTexto>";
   soap = soap + "  </soap:Body>";
   soap = soap + "</soap:Envelope>";
       return soap;
   }

   function callComplete(result, data)
   {
       if (result)
       {
         //alert(getTagValue(data, "TesteDeTextoResult"));
           document.getElementById('MTextArea1').value = getTagValue(data, "TesteDeTextoResult");
       }
       else
       {
           alert("Error occurred calling web service.\n" + result + "\n" +data);
       }
   }
   function testarTexto()
   {

       var soap = createSoapHeader("TESTE");
       //document.getElementById('texto').value = soap;
//     alert(soap);

       var webServiceCall = new WebSvc();

       webServiceCall.CallWebService("http://localhost/WebService/Test.asmx", soap, callComplete);
   }

   function getTagValue(inputStr, tagName)
   {

       var stag = "<" + tagName + ">";
       var etag = "<" + "/" + tagName + ">";

       var startPos = inputStr.indexOf(stag, 0);
       if (startPos >= 0)
       {
           var endPos = inputStr.indexOf(etag, startPos);
           if (endPos > startPos)
           {
               startPos = startPos + stag.length;
               return inputStr.substring(startPos, endPos);
           }
       }

       return "";
   }
```

But it only works with methods that return a string as result. How can I make when I need to return a dataSet?

Comment: Did my answer help? If so, please mark the answer as correct. Otherwise ask again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Just use jQuery ^^ There you find a lot of different handlers for different return types. A dataSet could be encoded in JSON or XML, what is transfered automatically into JS data structures by jQuery. Additionally, the JS code looks much cleaner, because jQuery comes with a bunch of [AJAX methods](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/). To transform the xml response into JS data structures, just set the `dataType` to `xml` in your jQuery request. For instance:

```
jQuery.ajax('url/to/your/WS', {
   dataType: "xml",
   data: {
      postParam1 : "foo"
   },
   success: function(data) {
      alert(data.find("MyNode"));
   }
});
```

How to work with the parsed xml response in JS can be found [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery).

Comment: If I send the Field Name to *getTagValue* method It works...but only the first row...how can I do to do a Looping in all the rows from result? Look at the *getTagValue* method, pls

Comment: On the page I have posted you can find this one: $(xml).find("Tutorial").each(function() !! With this you loop trough every element with the name "Tutorial"... btw, manually parsing a xml string with string operations is not a good idea. Please update your code using my answer for further questions,thank you